# JavaFx Center Progress Indicator with ScrollPane

Tags: java, javafx, spinner

I need to center the progress indicator in the middle of screen the contains an image like this:

```
          <BorderPane>
            <center>
                    <ScrollPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                        <content>
                            <HBox alignment="CENTER">
                                <children>
                                    <ProgressIndicator fx:id="progressIndicator" progress="0.0" visible="false"/>
                                    <ImageView fx:id="imageView" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true"/>
                                </children>
                            </HBox>
                        </content>
                    </ScrollPane>
                </center>
            </BorderPane>
```

when i remove the scroolPane the spinner is centered ?

Answer (score 0):

use of StackPane is the solution:

```
            <center>
                <StackPane>
                    <ScrollPane fx:id="imageContainer" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                        <content>
                            <ImageView fx:id="imageView" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true"/>
                        </content>
                    </ScrollPane>
                    <ProgressIndicator fx:id="progressIndicator" progress="0.0" visible="false"/>
                </StackPane>
            </center>
```